# VirtualBox - Is it possible to flash an already-configured OS from Virtualbox to another Machine?

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtualbox

I have an RPi 2B + and want to configure it, and i want to install some plugins(Tensorflow, etc etc etc). Downloading it at home is also not an option because my internet connection is really slow(50-60kb/s).

Just wondering if this is possible:

1. Emulate Raspbian on VirtualBox
2. Configure, download plugins
3. Export Raspbian
4. Flash it in Rpi

Remote access is also not an option because my router (Huawei, i forgot the model. It was provided by my ISP) doesn't support port-forwarding.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! this question seems to have nothing to do with programming. It may be closed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partly it is possible.

VirtualBox can not emulate an arm processor !

so you could only do a start by downloading the raspian image for x86 (scroll down on the download page)
once you are happy with the results you would have to install everything (python, tf ....) on the pi. You could copy the code not the libraries as of the mentioned arm support
makes sense ?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the delayed response! I tried this, did some trial and error steps to get the expected output, and then did it on the RPI. Thanks!